# Return images back to normal when user scrolls to top again

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I have 2 static (*html position: fixed;*) images at the edges of the screen (right and left). When users scrolls more than 100 pixels from top, these edges **retract** 50 pixels.

I want to them to **reappear** (normal again, as they were at the beginning) when users scrolls back to top. I tried adding boolean value which is true when they retract and added it to condition when they need to reappear again. But it isn't working. Why?

```
userHasScrolled = false;

$(document).ready(function(){
 $(window).scroll(function(){
 if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
  $(".rightstatic").animate({marginRight:'-50px'}, 900);
  $(".leftstatic").animate({marginLeft:'-50px'}, 900);
  userHasScrolled = true;
 }
 });
});

if($(window).scrollTop() <= 0 && userHasScrolled) {
  $(".rightstatic").animate({marginRight: '+50px'}, 400);
  $(".leftstatic").animate({marginLeft:'+50px'}, 400);
  userHasScrolled = false;
}
```

**Edit:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(window).scroll(function(){
   if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
     $(".rightstatic").animate({marginRight:'-20px'}, 900);
     $(".leftstatic").animate({marginLeft:'-20px'}, 900);
   } else if($(window).scrollTop() <= 0) {
     $(".rightstatic").animate({marginRight: '+0px'}, 400);
     $(".leftstatic").animate({marginLeft:'+0px'}, 400);
   }
 });
});
```

It kinda works, but has a HUGE delay. Like more than a minute after reaching top it retracts back.

**Edit 2:** After throttling it finally works. Thanks @TomaszBubała.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't working because the bottom part of your code is called only once and `userHasScrolled` is `false` by that time. You need to combine both inside `$(window).scroll()`. I think you can get rid of `userHasScrolled` variable and second condition could be just `else` instead of `else if`.

```
var scrollTimeout;
var throttle = 250;
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(window).scroll(function(){
   if(scrollTimeout) return;
   scrollTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
     scrollTimeout = null;
     const scrolled = $(this).scrollTop();
     if (scrolled > 100) {
       console.log("1");
       $(".rightstatic").animate({marginRight:'-20px'}, 900);
       $(".leftstatic").animate({marginLeft:'-20px'}, 900);
     } else {
       console.log("2");
       $(".rightstatic").animate({marginRight: '+0px'}, 400);
       $(".leftstatic").animate({marginLeft:'+0px'}, 400);
     }
   }, throttle);
 });
});
```

### Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wctxbynt/41/

### EDIT:

It wasn't working as intended since `scroll` event is fired multiple times (tens of times) with a single mousewheel interaction, causing jQuery animate to be called far too many times than it needs to be. A common way to fix this problem is to "throttle" a function not to be called unless a certain amount of time has passed. In edited code above we define timeout as `250ms`, which means that our scroll handler code will get called up to 4 times a second - not more (a *big* difference as opposed to ex. 30 times in 100ms which is huge improvement in performance). Above is just an easy implementation of throttle function - [read more about throttling here](https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/).

Comment: Tried with else if, and without it. Edges don't retract back. Any idea why?

Comment: can you create a fiddle or any live example so we can work on that?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/agarsky/wctxbynt/10/#&togetherjs=E3TAocC23q I hope am I doing this right.

Comment: Seems that to get it right (it so delayed right now!) we need to throttle scroll function

Comment: Do you know an easy way to do that?

Comment: Edited my answer :)